# How can I see the line number of a searched text?

Tags: grep, search

Suppose, I have a text file named `output.txt` which contains 1.46 million rows of data.

I want to search a text `27QL` in the file.

If the text exists, Linux should return the line number.

How can I do that?

Can I use `grep`? If Yes, how?

Comment: Saying *the* line number makes an implicit assumption: that the text you seek is unique within the file. You need to consider (and deal with) other outcomes: (a) the text is not present int the file; (b) the text is present multiple times in the file. You might also consider whether the data is organised into fields, and if so whether the value should only be selected from particular fields in the records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `grep` utility has a standard option, `-n`, which will cause it to prepend its ordinary output with the line number on which `grep` matched the pattern. The line number will be delimited from the contents of the line by a colon.

```bsh
grep -n -F -w '27QL' file
```

Here, I've also used the non-standard `-w` option to only search for complete words, which means we won't match `127QL` or `27QLA`. With `-F`, you tell `grep` that your pattern is a *string* and not a regular expression.

To remove the actual data from the output (i.e. extract only the line numbers), pass the output through `cut`:

```bsh
grep -n -F -w '27QL' file |
cut -d : -f 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/27QL/=' infile
```

the switch `-n` for the sed silent the default print action and with `=` sign in `/pattern/=` it will only print the line number of the matted pattern.

---

or even using `awk`, a more powerful text-processing tool over the `grep`/`sed`:

```
awk '/27QL/{ print NR }' infile
```

`NR` in awk represent the **N**umber of **R**ecord.